# Codeigniter urls, doubled segment, like: news/news/

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I have completed the well known 'news' toutorial included in CI documentation. sometimes double 'news/' segment occurs in my linking strings like this: '/codeig/news/news/entry' and sometimes after reloading page everything works right. i should mention i have got rid of 'index.php' segment following another popular tutorial. what is wrong with my code ?

this is my routing:

```
$route['news/create'] = 'news/create'; 
$route['news/update/(:any)'] = 'news/update/$1';
$route['news/delete/(:any)'] = 'news/delete/$1';
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
$route['news'] = 'news';
$route['welcome'] = 'welcome';

$route['auth/(:any)'] = 'auth/$1';
$route['auth'] = 'auth';
$route['activate/:num/:any'] = "/auth/activate/$1/$2";
$route['reset_password/:num/:any'] = "/auth/reset_password/$1/$2";

$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'news';
```

views/news/index.php file:

```
<?php foreach ($news as $news_item): ?>

<h2><?php echo $news_item['title'] ?></h2>
<div id="main">
    <?php echo $news_item['text'] ?>
</div>
<p><a href="news/<?php echo $news_item['slug'] ?>">View article</a></p>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

view method (news controller)

```
public function view($slug)
{
$data['news_item'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);

if (empty($data['news_item']))
{
    show_404();
}

$data['title'] = $data['news_item']['title'];

$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
$this->load->view('news/view', $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

Comment: We can't tell what's wrong with your code because you're not showing us any...

Comment: well, that is code taken from original CI documentation.

Comment: How are you constructing the URL's that output the doubled segment i.e. `news/news/`? Can you post that code?

Comment: I had the same issue.... I think it's a typo. I changed `<a href="news/` to `<a href="view/` and everything worked fine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In HTML, if the current URL is something like this:

> `http://example.com/news/`

And you have links like this:

```
<a href="news/article-slug">Link</a>
```

After clicking the link, your URL will end up being:

> `http://example.com/news/news/article-slug`

If you clicked it again, you'd have:

> `http://example.com/news/news/article-slug/news/article-slug`

**Note**: This isn't exactly right, the relativity of the path does depend on whether or not there's a trailing slash `/` in the current URL and/or your links.

`href="news/something"` is a **relative** URL, relative to the current page. You want to use either absolute or rooted URLs:

```
<a href="http://example.com/mysite/news/article-slug">Link</a>
<a href="/news/article-slug">Link</a>
```

Use any of the following Codeigniter functions to make absolute URLs easier:

- `anchor()` (makes the whole link for you)
- `site_url()` (returns your absolute base URL)
- `base_url()` (same as above)

```
<?php echo anchor('news/'.$news_item['slug'], 'Link Text'); ?>
<a href="<?php echo base_url('news/'.$news_item['slug']); ?>">Link Text</a>
```

So just to clarify, this has nothing to do with your routing - it's purely a problem with relative links in your HTML.

Comment: great answer btw @Madmartigan you now have a new follower in twitter land :)

Answer (score 2):

A less detailed explanation:

In the file 'application/views/news/index.php'

**Before** (causing /news/news/ in URL):

```
<p><a href="news/<?php echo $news_item['slug'] ?>">View article</a></p>
```

**After** (fixed):

```
<p><a href="<?php echo $news_item['slug'] ?>">View article</a></p>
```

`news/` is included in `$news_item['slug']` so doesn't need to be in the HTML.